# How do I conditionally delete a row if the value actually exists in sql?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to run this command in my rails database:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
      "delete from data_migrations where version = '2017010417100'"
  )
```

but only if the version number actually exists. In short, I'm unsure if the version exists and I want to delete it in case it exists. I can't access the database directly due to protocol at my company. What can I do?

I'm trying to run a data migration to fix some records but it may have accidentally run already.

Comment: An SQL `delete` whose `where` clause doesn't match any rows does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  "if exists(select 1 from data_migrations where version = '2017010417100') delete from data_migrations where version = '2017010417100'")
```

You ask first if exist that version, if exist execute the query